# Can you do true p2p video streaming in Flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, video-streaming, p2p

I need to stream video (Camera + microphone) from a Flash client to another Flash client. I need to do it true p2p style, with no server interference at any point whatsoever.

I have been searching around but can only find references to Cirrus (server tech). Is what I want possible?

Comment: You need some way to manage the URLS of the clients.

Comment: Say I have a way to know the address of each one...

Comment: it can not be a browser based app. It will have to be an AIR app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flash currently has p2p video streaming available : It is the rtmfp protocol.

This protocol allows two Flash clients to share data (and is the only method to do so in-browser with Flash only). It natively support audio/video transfer, as well as serialized objects.

It works in two possible modes :

- If all the clients are in the same local network, they can communicate with each-other without needing a server. AFAIK, they detect each other using network discovery.
- If the clients are in different networks (as it usually is through the web), it needs a server to store and maintain a list of currently connected clients : audio/video data is still share directly between the clients, and the server only exists to know who and where are the clients. Officially, you need a Flash Media Server for that, but there a few projects of free rtmfp-compatible servers out there.

If you want/need to use a different solution, you will need either a non-Flash solution if you want to be in-browser, or an AIR if you don't need to be in a browser.

As a side-note : most, if not all, p2p protocols use servers to manage a client list. It is, for example, the case of the BitTorrent protocol.